Add a templated attribute to a class?
I want to define a class like,
    template<int N> class A{

    public:
    template<int D> B<D>* InstanceofB;

    void methodofClassA(input){
     methodofClassB(input);
     }

    }

where,
    template<int X> class B{
    Some methods..
    }

The goal is to associate a specific instance of class B with an instance of class A, such that on invoking methodofClassA(input) it uses this specific instance of class B to evaluate and return an expression.
However, I get an error in class A declaration as "member InstanceofB declared as a template.
How do I resolve this?

The variable template as data member should be static. See working demo where I've added static.

This is not a [mcve]. You're missing ;.

It looks like you want every object of type A<1> to contain a member of type B<0>*, a member of type B<1>*, a member of type B<-1>*, a member of type B<2>*, ....

there are so many typos in the code that are unrelated to the quesiton. They make it unnecessarily difficult to understand what you want. Is methodofClassB(input); supposed to be InstanceofB.methodofClassB(input); ? How (and when) do you determine what D should be? Should each call to methodofClassA use the same methodofClassB ? Should each instantiation of A use the same D ?

Yes it is InstanceofB.methodofClassB(input). I had assumed the naming it was enough. D is determined in the main file. It changes evry run and hence can be only decided before running main. Thus each of instance of A uses a different D. The methodofClassA though uses the same methodofClassB

You could add the template parameter to A
    template<int X> class B {};
    
    template<int N, int D> class A{
    
    public:
    B<D>* InstanceofB;
    
    void methodofClassA(){
    }
    
    };
    
    int main() {
        //Instantiate A with both template params
        A<1,2> a;
    
    }

Juste note that to call the methodofClassB you'd have to write
InstanceofB->methodofClassB(input);

I tried this but it breaks too many things in the code.

When you have a variable template as data member, it needs to be static.
Thus, the error can be solve as shown below:
template<int X> class B{
  
};
template<int N> class A{

public:
//------------------vvvvvv--------------------->added static here
    template<int D> static  B<D>* InstanceofB;

    void methodofClassA()
    {
    }

};

Demo

Thanks! But each instance of class A should be linked to a different instance of class B. I think making it static will not allow this.

@IndrajitWadgaonkar Yes, static will now allow that.  In your question title you used the word "attribute" which usually means class state which is what static does. Additionally, a non-static member can't be a variable template. You're welcome.

I will try this. I assume since this is a variable template the instances are treated as different variables allowing each instance of class A to be linked to a different instance of class B as required. Thanks :)

@IndrajitWadgaonkar Yes, each A<N> will have a single separate static member. But instances of A<N> will all share this member.

But when I do inside main() as int main(){ B<3> ObjB; A<2> objA; objA. InstanceofB=objB;} I get an error " Use of variable template  InstanceofB requires template arguments".

@IndrajitWadgaonkar You need to add asterisk * because InstanceofB is a pointer. Also, you need to pass a template parameter because InstanceofB it is a variable template. See working demo I created for you to see this more easily.
